# Difference between using NSLayoutConstraints initializer compared to Anchors for setting constraints

Tags: swift, autolayout, anchor, nslayoutconstraint

Why do some developers add constraints like this:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
```

And some like this:

```swift
myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

They basically do the same thing... right? So what is the difference between them? Why should one be used instead of the other? Is there a performance difference for using one over the other?

At the place I worked our iOS lead was using the `NSLayoutConstraint` initialization way exclusively and everyone was forced to do the same to have more consistency and readability throughout the entire code, I like both ways, I just want to know if there was/is ever any benefit of using one over the other? Or are the differences just based on preference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In large part, it is new syntax and readability, but there are still some things that you can do with `NSLayoutConstraint(...)` that you cannot do the "new" way.

For example, let's take a simple task of adding a `UILabel` centered horizontally, 40-pts from the bottom. Each of the following examples will begin with this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myView = UILabel()
    myView.backgroundColor = .green
    myView.text = "Hello"
    
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    
    // add constraints....

}
```

So, our first method looks like this:

```
        // center horizontally
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        
        // bottom = 40-pts from view Bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: -40.0).isActive = true
```

We can get the exact same results using this syntax, which would generally be considered more "readable":

```
        // center horizontally
        myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        // bottom = 40-pts from view Bottom
        myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0).isActive = true
```

Now, we'll usually have many more constraints to set, so we can make it even more readable with this (eliminates the `.isActive = true` at the end of every line):

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // center horizontally
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            // bottom = 40-pts from view Bottom
            myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])
```

---

So... What happens if we throw in just a little complexity, such as saying *"Keep the Bottom of the Label **20%** from the bottom of the view"*?

---

To stick with the "new, more readable" syntax, we have a couple options...

1 - constrain the bottom of the Label to the bottom of the view, wait until layout is finished - so we know the height of the view - and then set the `.constant` on the bottom anchor to `-(view height * 0.2)`. That will work, but we have to re-calculate every time the label's superview changes (such as on device rotation).

2 - add a `UIView` as a "bottom spacer":

```
        // add a hidden UIView for bottom "space"
        let spacerView = UIView()
        spacerView.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(spacerView)
        spacerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // spacerView at bottom, height = 20% of view height
            spacerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            spacerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),

            // center horizontally
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            // bottom = spacerView Top
            myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
```

That works, and handles superview size changes, but we've added another view to the view hierarchy. For this simple example, no big deal, but we probably don't want to add a bunch of them for a complex layout.

3 - add a `UILayoutGuide` as a "bottom spacer":

```
        // add a UILayoutGuide for bottom "space"
        let spacerGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        view.addLayoutGuide(spacerGuide)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // spacerGuide at bottom, height = 20% of view height
            spacerGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            spacerGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            
            // center horizontally
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            // bottom = spacerGuide Top
            myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacerGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
```

Accomplishes the same thing, but now we're using a *non-rendering* UI element so we're not weighing down the view hierarchy.

4 - ***Use the `NSLayoutConstraint(...)`*** syntax, and avoid all of that:

```
        // center horizontally
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        
        // bottom = 80% of view bottom (leaves 20% space at bottom)
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           multiplier: 0.8,
                           constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    }
```

So, *for most situations*, it is a matter of preference and/or consistency, but you will find the occasional case where there ***is*** a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors were added later. They look cleaner and you can more easily constrain to the safe area as it has its own anchors.

Comment: Maybe worth knowing... you can easily constrain to **Safe Area** with `NSLayoutConstraint(...)` by using `toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`